# Clojure http-kit: get query params as map?

Tags: clojure, http-kit

I have a server with an endpoint `.../end2` which I send parameters to, such as:

```
.../end2?a=2&b=1
```

How do I get a map `{:a 2 :b 1}`? I thought  `(:params request)` is the way to go but I get an empty map..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using compojure, the params are not automatically bound to the request, and ring middleware must be applied to do this:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/end2" request (str (:params request))))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
      ring.middleware.params/wrap-params))

(run-server #'app {:port 8888})
```

Comment: Worth to note, for those learning Clojure like me, that REQUIRING things is super important, otherwise you'll spend half an hour debugging why the SO solution does not work XD

Answer (score -1):

You need to add ring middle ware to parse params. You could check [ring default](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults)

You don't have to worry about nested params or others.